# Node JS Base Router being overwritten

Tags: javascript, node.js

My `server.js` file looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// event listener
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// set the home page route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('home page loaded');
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

I'm new to node/express but hoping for some clarification. I thought `app.get('/', ...` would handle the default functionality. But instead of logging the message to the console, it's loading `index.html` from `/public` when I run `node server.js`.

What is overwriting the routing functionality here? In case it helps, express version is 4.11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this problem due to [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) module which is middleware that you are using with: `express.static()`

Note from its documentation:

> By default this module will send "index.html" files in response to a request on a directory. To disable this set false or to supply a new index pass a string or an array in preferred order.

i.e. replace:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

with:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public',{'index':false}));`